# nbsphinx causes build to fail when building Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

### Details

I am getting a build failure of my read-the-docs that I don't understand.  The assertion of "verbatim" in line 2151 of nbsphinx.py is causing the build failure.  So the build fails when I try to include the Jupyter Notebook tutorials I created.  I compared current versions of the tutorials to previous versions which had not caused the build to fail, and I can't find a difference that could account for the current failure.

- Read the Docs project URL: lofti_gaia
- Build URL: https://github.com/logan-pearce/lofti_gaia
- Read the Docs username: logan-pearce

### Expected Result

A passing build including *.ipynb files

### Actual Result

Build failed at line 2151 of nbsphinx.py due to assertion of 'Verbatim' failing.

Terminal output:

```
Running Sphinx v4.1.2
loading translations [en]... done
making output directory... done
WARNING: html_static_path entry '_static' does not exist
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [latex]: all documents
updating environment: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
looking for now-outdated files... none found
processing lofti_gaia.tex... index installation tutorials/QuickStart tutorials/Tutorial api lofti loftitools 
resolving references...
done
writing... failed

Exception occurred:
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/lofti-gaia/conda/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbsphinx.py", line 2151, in depart_codearea_latex
    assert 'Verbatim' in lines[0]
AssertionError
The full traceback has been saved in /tmp/sphinx-err-x1h83s3m.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers.
Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message can be provided next time.
A bug report can be filed in the tracker at <https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues>. Thanks!
```

Comment: Please do not paste images of text. Instead paste the actual error message.

Answer (score 3):

According to the github issue 584 for nbsphinx (https://github.com/spatialaudio/nbsphinx/issues/584), this is due to a compatibility issue with sphinx 4.1.0. It can be gotten around by requiring sphinx version 4.0.2.

So in my `requirements.txt` file, I included `sphinx==4.0.2`, after which the build passes. So now my `requirements.txt` file looks like:

```
numpy
matplotlib
astropy>=4.0.1.post1
astroquery>=0.4
sphinx==4.0.2
ipython==7.19.0
nbsphinx>=0.8.6
```

and the build passes.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue. I did not solve it with .ipynb format, but converting the jupyter notebook to .rst format works.

May it helps